# "New Contributor" label not showing when a question is migrated

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, new-contributor-indicator

When a question is migrated, at least from a main site to a meta site, the "new contributor" label is not shown below the user card.

Here is an example from Ask Ubuntu Meta

[Reputation prevents any feedback from new users](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19011/reputation-prevents-any-feedback-from-new-users)

Also one from Stack Overflow Meta

[Is it possible to claim a Stack Overflow account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396117/is-it-possible-to-claim-a-stack-overflow-account)

In both cases the accounts are less than a week old and have only 1 rep, so should get the label.

I thought this was specific to Ask Ubuntu at first but it seems that it possibly would effect every site.

Due to the criteria for the label to show, examples are a bit hard to come by but I will add them as  I find them.

Comment: It looks like migrated questions don't get the ["new contributor when posted" mark](/questions/314472/what-are-the-exact-criteria-for-the-new-contributor-indicator-to-be-shown) that results in the indicator being shown. I've linked to the exact criteria for it to be shown, but basically, the mark is attached to the post, not to the user, so there sometimes can be weird bugs resulting from the mark not being attached when it should be, or [mistakenly being attached when it shouldn't](/questions/329421/remove-new-contributor-indicators-that-are-no-longer-applicable-when-an-account).